# How can I surround the lines inside the html tag object?

Tags: visual-mode, filetype-html, plugin-vim-surround

I have the following piece of HTML:

```
<div>
  <section>
  </section>
</div>
```

I would like to wrap the 2 section tags in a single article like so:

```
<div>
  <article>
    <section>
    </section>
  </article>
</div>
```

I have [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) installed.

If I <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd><article></kbd> I get:

```
<div><article>
  <section>
  </section>
</article></div>
```

How can I surround the lines inside the tag object?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>vitVS<article></kbd> seems to do what you want.

- <kbd>v</kbd> to start select mode
- <kbd>it</kbd> to select "inner tag"
- <kbd>V</kbd> to start line-wise visual mode
- <kbd>S<article></kbd> to surround

It would be better to start with line-wise visual mode, and go from there, but <kbd>it</kbd> changes it back to 'normal' (non-line wise) visual mode.

Comment: Unforunately not :( as switching to line-wise visual mode gets the opening <div> tag and you end up with:


<article>
  <div>
    <section>
    </section>
  </article>
</div>

Comment: Hmm, the `it` motion seems to behave different depending on the HTML: I've "discovered" 4 different behaviours :-/

Comment: It works if you start on the section tag rather than on the div tag. Selects inside section, then V to just select those 2 lines. As opposed to selecting inside div, which selects part of the first line as well. Or you can go to the section tag and do `vatVS` to select around the section tag.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the `it` text-object starts right after the opening tag with a zero-width match.

The only solution I see is to visually select the lines you want with `V{motion}` before pressing `S`. It is less magical than `ysit<article>` but oh well…

Answer (score 1):

*Discl.*: This is not a Surround answer, just (three into) one that give(s) the result your are expecting -- note: there is a big limitation, Surround can work with any tag, here you'll have to known your tags in advance (well, lh-brackets could ask for the tag to insert, but that wouldn't be very ergonomic) .

With [lh-brackets](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets/), it'll be solved with:

```
:Brackets <div> </div> -nl -insert=0 -trigger=µ
```

Then you select your lines and hit `µ`. The magic is in the `-nl` flag.

Otherwise, you have the old way (define your own mapping) ... As I though, I've answered to a very similar question not so long ago, but on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28699590/wrapping-of-selected-string/28700179#28700179).

```
:xnoremap µ S<div><cr><c-r>"</div><esc>
" select your lines, hit µ, and then, you'll need to reindent

" or
xnoremap µ <esc>`>o<div><esc>`<O</div><esc>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yS` along with `at` to surround the `<section>` tags instead of doing a surrounding inside with `it` on the `<div>`. So you command will look like so:

```
<cr>ySat<article><cr>
```

The `<cr>` just moves to the start to the next line, a `j` would do just as well.

The alternative is to use visual mode linewise as other suggested. e.g. `vitVS<article><cr>`

For more help see:

```
:h yS
```

Comment: To avoid indentation issues in your second suggestoin: replace the t in vitVS<article><cr> with a, so: `vatS<article><cr>`. That said, there is still the issue with the article tags not being on their own lines: [gif](https://i.gyazo.com/0ca24a2d8ed48adf09e1b23f707b074e.mp4). Any idea on how to fix that?